# Android: how to get application label in UsageStats

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

I am able to get the usage statistics of the app using the UsgaeStatsManager like below

```
UsageStatsManager usm = getUsageStatsManager(context);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
long endTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis(); 

List<UsageStats> usageStatsList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,startTime,endTime);

for (UsageStats u : usageStatsList){
   Log.d(TAG, "Pkg: " + u.getPackageName() +  "\t" + "ForegroundTime: "
                + u.getTotalTimeInForeground() + " milliseconds") ;
}
```

When I get the output then it comes like below:

```
Pkg:com.skype.raiderForeground used time in ms:23922
Pkg:com.google.android.youtubeForeground used time in ms:0
Pkg:com.sec.android.app.chromecustomizationsForeground used time in ms:0
Pkg:com.whatsappForeground used time in ms:1665723
.
.
.
```

Which is correct but I want to get this list with names of apps in more user readable format like

```
Pkg:skype Foreground used time in ms:23922
Pkg:youtube Foreground used time in ms:0
Pkg:whatsapp Foreground used time in ms:1665723
```

I am wondering if we have any api similar to api applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString(); in PackageManager which gives the user readable package name instead of technical name of package. Or, is there any other way to print the simple name of the package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to get the AppName using package name

```
private String getAppNameFromPackage(String packageName, Context context) {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

        for (ResolveInfo app : pkgAppsList) {
            if (app.activityInfo.packageName.equals(packageName)) {
                return app.activityInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

You can print for loop like this,

```
for (UsageStats u : usageStatsList){
    Log.d(TAG, "Pkg: " + getAppNameFromPackage(u.getPackageName(), context) +  "\t" + "ForegroundTime: "
            + u.getTotalTimeInForeground() + " milliseconds") ;
}
```

It will give result like

```
Pkg:skype Foreground used time in ms:23922
Pkg:youtube Foreground used time in ms:0
Pkg:whatsapp Foreground used time in ms:1665723
```

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for the answer but it returned null value in some cases where the app was used in foreground for example:

Pkg: Original name: com.sec.android.app.launcher, modified name: null , ForegroundTime: 789958 milliseconds

Pkg: Original name: com.android.systemui, modified name: null , ForegroundTime: 14188 milliseconds

modified name is printed with getAppNameFromPackage(u.getPackageName(), context)